# SublimeText 3 - Package Control: Removed directory for orphaned package ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I am running SublimeText 3 (build 3083).  I follow the manual install directions for the ColdFusion plugin as described here (https://github.com/SublimeText/ColdFusion):

> Download Manually
>
> - Download the files using the GitHub .zip download option
> - Unzip the files and rename the folder to ColdFusion
> - Copy the folder to your Sublime Text 2 Packages directory

This has worked (and still works) on many machines.  But today I have a PC that each time I re-open SublimeText it removes the ColdFusion directory and in the SublimeText console it says "Package Control: Removed directory for orphaned package ColdFusion".  Haven't been able to find anything on this yet.  Help appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: If you haven't been there yet, http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/ might be a better place to get help with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "Download Manually" section is for Sublime Text 2 only. At the very top of the README you linked are the [ST3 instructions](https://github.com/SublimeText/ColdFusion#sublime-text-3):

> The development branch contains a rewrite of the ColdFusion plugin. The only installation method is via Git.
>
> ```
> cd Packages/
> git clone https://github.com/SublimeText/ColdFusion.git
> cd ColdFusion
> git checkout development
> ```

On Windows machines, the `Packages` folder is in `%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages`. You'll need to have a working copy of `git` on your machine, which can be obtained [here](http://git-scm.com/downloads).

Alternatively, you can download a zip file of the [development branch](https://github.com/SublimeText/ColdFusion/archive/development.zip), extract it, rename the resulting `ColdFusion-development` folder to `ColdFusion`, then copy that into your `Packages` folder.

---

### EDIT

I did a little digging, and apparently this package is no longer being developed. However, the [**`CFML`**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CFML) package has been suggested as a replacement. Not being a ColdFusion user, I haven't tested it myself, but reviews from others are good. It's available for ST3 only, but *can* be installed directly via Package Control, so you don't have to worry about using git.

Comment: I don't know much about git, we don't use it or have it installed.  I always did the manual install and it has always worked.  I tried your development branch download and that worked, the Coldfusion directory doesn't get deleted anymore.  I always downloaded from the link in my original question, I guess they are different or something has changed since I last downloaded it.  Thanks.

Comment: I've been looking for this the past 3 hours! Thanks MattDMo

Comment: Worked fine on windows; doesn't shows in the list of languages on Linux (XUbuntu)

Comment: @KunalB. where did you clone it in Linux?

Comment: `/home/kunalb/Applications/sublime_text_3/Packages/ColdFusion`

Comment: @KunalB. that's why. It should be `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages`.

Comment: @KunalB. doing a little digging, it looks like you'd be better off installing [`CFML`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CFML) through Package Control. Apparently the ColdFusion package is no longer being maintained.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110680/discussion-between-kunal-b-and-mattdmo).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sublime Text 3 `ST3`, the recommended package to use is the one named `CFML` available via `Package Control` here: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CFML

If  you are using Sublime Text 2 `ST2`, the recommended package is the one named `Cold​Fusion` available via `Package Control` here: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ColdFusion

For both of them you'll find there installation instructions using `Package Control` or manually from `GitHub`.